# Date Formatting in VBScript - Prefix Month with 0 (zero) e.g. 07 instead of 7

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, vbscript, formatting

If i use

> DatePart("m",Now()) ' out put will be 7

but my requirment is to display "07" rather than "7"

Is there any direct method to achieve this, or should should I write custom code to prefix "0" zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

they easy solution would be

`right( "0" & DatePart("m",Now()) ,2)`

Comment: Gee... ty :)
You saved my time!